# Using OCaml cohttp Client.post method

Tags: http-post, ocaml

I'm trying to use the OCaml cohttp package to send a POST request using the Client.post method. I looked at the example in [ocaml-cohttp/lib_test/test_net_lwt_client_and_server.ml](https://github.com/mirage/ocaml-cohttp/blob/90014aedf504da6835c08c6006682c38d4bdb783/lib_test/test_net_lwt_client_and_server.ml) to use the method, here's a code snippet from the example which uses the function.

`Client.post ~body:(Cohttp_lwt_body.of_string "barfoo") url`

I'm using the function exactly the same way in my own code:

```
Client.post ~body:(Cohttp_lwt_body.of_string bodyString) (Uri.of_string stringURI) >>= function
                            | Some (_, body) -> Cohttp_lwt_body.string_of_body body
                            | None -> return ""
```

But I get the error message:

```
Error: This pattern matches values of type 'a option
   but a pattern was expected which matches values of type
     Cohttp.Response.t * Cohttp_lwt_body.t
```

I looked at https://github.com/mirage/ocaml-cohttp/issues/64 which suggested changing the `~body` label to `?body` but then I got a different error:

```
Error: This expression has type Cohttp_lwt_body.t
   but an expression was expected of type Cohttp_lwt_body.t option
```

Could someone please explain how to use this function correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message indicates that this is a typing issue:

```
Error: This pattern matches values of type 'a option
   but a pattern was expected which matches values of type
     Cohttp.Response.t * Cohttp_lwt_body.t
```

Your `function` body to the right of the bind (`>>=`) should be rewritten to handle the tuple returned by `Client.post` rather than an `option` type.  For example:

```
Client.post
  ~body:(Cohttp_lwt_body.of_string bodyString)
  (Uri.of_string stringURI)
>>= fun (response, body) ->
match response with
| { Cohttp.Response.status = `OK; _ } -> ok_response_action body
| { Cohttp.Response.status; _ } -> other_response_action status body
```

cohttp does not, unfortunately, currently have easily accessible documentation.  You would need to reference the `.mli` files from the source directly.  For example, see [here](https://github.com/mirage/ocaml-cohttp/blob/f631fa359871c0aaceaef1732542831553c6049a/lib/s.mli#L107) for information on the `Cohttp.Response.t` type's structure.